# Incorporating MySQL into RabbitMQ/Spring

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-mvc, rabbitmq

I've begun using RabbitMQ, along with Spring, and it seems like a great set of tools. However, I need to extend [this tutorial](https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-rabbitmq/) to update an SQL database every time a message is received. I understand the concept, and I'm thinking it would just update in Receiver.java once the message has been received, but I'm not sure how to link the database to this code.

Previously, I would use a .properties file with all the pertinent information to the database, and it would be handled. But I'm not sure how I could do something like that here. If anyone has any ideas, or any tutorials I can use to build out my program, that would be great!